# Sizing a ggplot precisely

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have got two ggplots, of which I want the size of the grey area to be exactly equal.

Now by playing around I can get very close by setting first plot width to 12 and second plot width to 14.

```
ggsave(filename="test1.png", myPlot, width = 12, height =12, dpi=300, units="cm", device='png')
ggsave(filename="test2.png", myPlot, width = 14, height =12, dpi=300, units="cm", device='png')
```

[image]

My question is whether I can pull some variable(s) from the first plot, so that I can automatically compute the right width for the second plot (ie, the width that makes the grey areas identical in size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the options already given by Allan, you might also find `ggh4x::force_panelsizes()` convenient to set sizes for plots (disclaimer: I wrote it).

```r
library(ggplot2)

a <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = cyl)) +
  geom_point()

b <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(y.sec = "axis")

a + ggh4x::force_panelsizes(rows = unit(4, "cm"), cols = unit(5, "cm"))
```

[image]

```r
b + ggh4x::force_panelsizes(rows = unit(4, "cm"), cols = unit(5, "cm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This works like a charm. Is there a way to retrieve the original width (in cm) of my first panel, so that I can use that as the default? (I tried the method in the other answer to do this, but this gave me 1null.)

Comment: No there isn't. The issue is the 'null' unit in grid, which broadly means: 'fill in every other type of unit first, then divide the remainder over the null units'. This makes it so that usually panel sizes adapt to the plotting window, but also makes it unpredictable because it cannot be known in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To be absolutely sure about the size of the panel, it is best to build both plots and copy the widths of one plot to the widths of the other.

Let's take two simple plots using built-in data.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()

p1
```

[image]

```r
p2
```

[image]

We can see that the width of the gray panel is different in the two plots.

Now we build both of these as a `gtable` - this is normally done as part of the ggplot print method, but we can halt it at the stage before it actually draws on screen so we have the plots as graphical objects:

```r
p1_built <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
p2_built <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
```

Now we simply copy the widths from first plot over to the second plot:

```r
p2_built$widths <- p1_built$widths
```

To draw them we can do:

```r
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(p1_built)
```

[image]

```r
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(p2_built)
```

[image]

Note that the panels are now exactly the same size.

An easier method, if you don't mind the plots both being on the same page, is to use patchwork. This is as simple as:

```r
library(patchwork)

p1 / p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>